# Multiple functions in javascript infinite loop

Tags: javascript

I'm working on my blog site and I came across the problem with infinity loop in javascript, on my site I have a plane, which is flying from city to another city and when it stops at a city, the speech bubble should pop up, which is working great for now, but only in 1 loop, so I am asking how should I make this javascript loop again and again, for infinite time. I found something like while (true) and for (;;), but these crashes my web. Here is the code which I want to loop:

```
var washington_start = setTimeout(washington_timer, 10000);
        var london_stop;
        var washington_start;
        var washington_stop;
        var brasilia_start;
        var brasilia_stop;

        function washington_timer() {
            document.getElementById("washington_info").style.opacity = '1';
            document.getElementById("washington_info").style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById("washington_info").style.transition = '.5s';
            document.getElementById("washington_info").style.zIndex = '4';
            document.getElementById("washington_info").style.backgroundColor = '#00aabb';
            document.getElementById("washington_info").style.scale = '1';
            document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url('img/washington.jpg')";
            document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundSize='cover';
            document.getElementById("bg").style.transition = '1s';
            washington_stop = setTimeout(washington_stoper, 3400);
        }

        function washington_stoper() {
            document.getElementById("washington_info").style.opacity = '0';
            document.getElementById("washington_info").style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById("washington_info").style.zIndex = '2';
            document.getElementById("washington_info").style.scale = '0';
            document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url('img/chata_blured.jpg')";
            document.getElementById("bg").style.transition = '1s';
            brasilia_start = setTimeout(brasilia_timer, 4250);
        }

        function brasilia_timer() {
            document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.opacity = '1';
            document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.transition = '.5s';
            document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.zIndex = '4';
            document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.backgroundColor = '#00aabb';
            document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.scale = '1';
            document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url('img/brasilia.jpg')";
            document.getElementById("bg").style.transition = '1s';
            brasilia_stop = setTimeout(brasilia_stoper, 6000);
        }

        function brasilia_stoper() {
            document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.opacity = '0';
            document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.zIndex = '2';
            document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.scale = '0';
            document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url('img/chata_blured.jpg')";
            document.getElementById("bg").style.transition = '1s';
            london_start = setTimeout(london_timer, 10000);
        }

        function london_timer() {
            document.getElementById("london_info").style.opacity = '1';
            document.getElementById("london_info").style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById("london_info").style.transition = '.5s';
            document.getElementById("london_info").style.zIndex = '4';
            document.getElementById("london_info").style.backgroundColor = '#00aabb';
            document.getElementById("london_info").style.scale = '1';
            document.getElementById("bg").style.transition = '1s';
            document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url('img/london.jpg')";
            london_stop = setTimeout(london_stoper, 6000);
        }

        function london_stoper() {
            document.getElementById("london_info").style.opacity = '0';
            document.getElementById("london_info").style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById("london_info").style.zIndex = '2';
            document.getElementById("london_info").style.scale = '0';
            document.getElementById("bg").style.transition = '1s';
            document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url('img/chata_blured.jpg')";
        }
```

Also I'm just starting with javascript so if it doesn't have any simple explanation, try to explain to me  little more, thank you!

Comment: Here is how the web looks like if I didn't explain it properly: http://pouze.kvalitne.cz/blog/

Comment: Either use `setInterval()` or setup the `setTimeout()` to be callable and call when the previous one finishes.

Comment: I don't see any loops in the code you provided. also, why are you creating a function with a 10,000 second delay? That doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved by just adding a `washington_start = setTimeout(washington_timer, 10000);` into the `london_stoper` function:

```js
var washington_start = setTimeout(washington_timer, 10000);
var london_stop;
var washington_start;
var washington_stop;
var brasilia_start;
var brasilia_stop;

function washington_timer() {
    document.getElementById("washington_info").style.opacity = '1';
    document.getElementById("washington_info").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("washington_info").style.transition = '.5s';
    document.getElementById("washington_info").style.zIndex = '4';
    document.getElementById("washington_info").style.backgroundColor = '#00aabb';
    document.getElementById("washington_info").style.scale = '1';
    document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url('img/washington.jpg')";
    document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundSize='cover';
    document.getElementById("bg").style.transition = '1s';
    washington_stop = setTimeout(washington_stoper, 3400);
}

function washington_stoper() {
    document.getElementById("washington_info").style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById("washington_info").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("washington_info").style.zIndex = '2';
    document.getElementById("washington_info").style.scale = '0';
    document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url('img/chata_blured.jpg')";
    document.getElementById("bg").style.transition = '1s';
    brasilia_start = setTimeout(brasilia_timer, 4250);
}

function brasilia_timer() {
    document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.opacity = '1';
    document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.transition = '.5s';
    document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.zIndex = '4';
    document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.backgroundColor = '#00aabb';
    document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.scale = '1';
    document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url('img/brasilia.jpg')";
    document.getElementById("bg").style.transition = '1s';
    brasilia_stop = setTimeout(brasilia_stoper, 6000);
}

function brasilia_stoper() {
    document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.zIndex = '2';
    document.getElementById("brasilia_info").style.scale = '0';
    document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url('img/chata_blured.jpg')";
    document.getElementById("bg").style.transition = '1s';
    london_start = setTimeout(london_timer, 10000);
}

function london_timer() {
    document.getElementById("london_info").style.opacity = '1';
    document.getElementById("london_info").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("london_info").style.transition = '.5s';
    document.getElementById("london_info").style.zIndex = '4';
    document.getElementById("london_info").style.backgroundColor = '#00aabb';
    document.getElementById("london_info").style.scale = '1';
    document.getElementById("bg").style.transition = '1s';
    document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url('img/london.jpg')";
    london_stop = setTimeout(london_stoper, 6000);
}

function london_stoper() {
    document.getElementById("london_info").style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById("london_info").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("london_info").style.zIndex = '2';
    document.getElementById("london_info").style.scale = '0';
    document.getElementById("bg").style.transition = '1s';
    document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url('img/chata_blured.jpg')";var washington_start = 
    setTimeout(washington_timer, 10000);
}
```

You can also avoid a lot of repetitive code by using an ES6 generator and CSS classes:

```js
const iterator=(function*(){
  const cities = [
    {city: 'washington', waitBefore: 10000, waitAfter: 3400},
    {city: 'brasilia', waitBefore: 4250, waitAfter: 6000},
    {city: 'london', waitBefore: 10000, waitAfter: 6000},

  ]
  const bgClass = document.getElementById('bg').classList
  function activate(city, flag){
    document.getElementById(city+'_info').classList.toggle('active', flag)
    bgClass.toggle(city, flag)
  }

  while(true)
    for(const {waitBefore, waitAfter, city} of cities){
      yield waitBefore
      activate(city, true)
      yield waitAfter
      activate(city, false)
    }
})()
(function iterate(t){
  setTimeout(() => iterate(iterator.next()), t)
})()
```

```css
[id$="_info"]{
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #00aabb;
  scale: 0;
}
[id$="_info"].active{
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 4;
  scale: 1;
}
#bg{
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('img/chata-blur.jpg');
  transition: 1s;
}
#bg.washington{
  background-image: url('img/washington.jpg');
}
#bg.brasilia{
  background-image: url('img/brasilia.jpg');
}
#bg.london{
  background-image: url('img/london.jpg');
}
```